# Bukkit: Making an inv clear when another command from another plugin was run

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I need to know if there is a way to clear a players inventory when they run a command from another plugin. I'm thinking you can use the PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent but I have not been able to get it myself. I would like some help with my problem. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track - create a listener for PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent, check the command is what you want, and then clear the player's inventory:

```
public class PlayerCommandPreprocessListener implements Listener {
    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerCommandPreprocess(PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent event) {
        if (event.getMessage().toLowerCase().startsWith("/otherplugincommand")) {
            event.getPlayer().getInventory().clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Remember to normalise the case before comparing (either call `toUpperCase()` or `toLowerCase()` on the message), as Bukkit's command processing is case insensitive.

Using `startsWith()` as opposed to `equals()` ignores any following arguments - if you need to check the arguments match exactly, use an `equals()` call.

Past that, actually clearing the player's inventory is trivial, and can be done in a one-liner.